# .NET RegionInfo class

Tags: c#, .net, globalization, regioninfo

When I try to create a new RegionInfo with certain ISO 3166 country codes ("BD" for Bangladesh, "SO" for Somalia, "LK" for Sri Lanka), I get an ArgumentException that says it's not recognized.

What's the deal? The Intellisense of RegionInfo(string) says it conforms to ISO 3166, but these country/region codes are not supported?

I don't get it.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

.NET doesn't provide all Cultures/Regions out-of-the-box. Note the 'predefined' RegionInfos here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.regioninfo(VS.80).aspx.

Unfortunately, if you want to use non-predefined Regions, you have to define them yourself. Here's the MSDN how-to: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms172469(VS.80).aspx.

Comment: second link is broken

Comment: web archive of the second link: https://web.archive.org/web/20140717034531/http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms172469(VS.80).aspx

Answer (score 4):

<strike>Some</strike>All of the regions you missed are now supported (in newer versions of the .NET Framework and of the operating system).

The following code finds all `RegionInfo` that are "reachable" from a specific culture:

```
foreach (var ri in CultureInfo.GetCultures(CultureTypes.SpecificCultures).Select(ci => new RegionInfo(ci.ToString())).OrderBy(x => x.TwoLetterISORegionName))
    Console.WriteLine("{0,3}: {1,11}: {2} ({3})", ri.TwoLetterISORegionName, ri, ri.EnglishName, ri.NativeName);
```

On my machine right now it gives:

```
001:      ar-001: World (العالم)
001:      en-001: World (World)
001:      eo-001: World (World)
001:      ia-001: World (World)
001:      la-001: World (World)
001:     prg-001: World (swītai)
001:      vo-001: World (World)
001:      yi-001: World (וועלט)
029:      en-029: Caribbean (Caribbean)
029:      fr-029: Caribbean (caraïbes)
029:     pap-029: Caribbean (Caribbean)
150:      en-150: Europe (Europe)
419:      es-419: Latin America (Latinoamérica)
 AD:       ca-AD: Andorra (Andorra)
 AE:       ar-AE: United Arab Emirates (الإمارات العربية المتحدة)
 AF:      prs-AF: Afghanistan (افغانستان)
 AF:       ps-AF: Afghanistan (افغانستان)
 AF:  uz-Arab-AF: Afghanistan (افغانستان)
 AG:       en-AG: Antigua and Barbuda (Antigua and Barbuda)
 AI:       en-AI: Anguilla (Anguilla)
 AL:       sq-AL: Albania (Shqipëri)
 AM:       hy-AM: Armenia (Հայաստան)
 AO:       ln-AO: Angola (Angóla)
 AO:       pt-AO: Angola (Angola)
 AR:       es-AR: Argentina (Argentina)
 AS:       en-AS: American Samoa (American Samoa)
 AT:       de-AT: Austria (Österreich)
 AT:       en-AT: Austria (Austria)
 AU:       en-AU: Australia (Australia)
 AW:       nl-AW: Aruba (Aruba)
 AX:       sv-AX: Åland Islands (Åland)
 AZ:  az-Cyrl-AZ: Azerbaijan (Азәрбајҹан)
 AZ:  az-Latn-AZ: Azerbaijan (Azərbaycan)
 BA:  bs-Cyrl-BA: Bosnia and Herzegovina (Босна и Херцеговина)
 BA:  bs-Latn-BA: Bosnia and Herzegovina (Bosna i Hercegovina)
 BA:       hr-BA: Bosnia and Herzegovina (Bosna i Hercegovina)
 BA:  sr-Cyrl-BA: Bosnia and Herzegovina (Босна и Херцеговина)
 BA:  sr-Latn-BA: Bosnia and Herzegovina (Bosna i Hercegovina)
 BB:       en-BB: Barbados (Barbados)
 BD:       bn-BD: Bangladesh (বাংলাদেশ)
 BE:       de-BE: Belgium (Belgien)
 BE:       en-BE: Belgium (Belgium)
 BE:       fr-BE: Belgium (Belgique)
 BE:       nl-BE: Belgium (België)
 BF:       fr-BF: Burkina Faso (Burkina Faso)
 BG:       bg-BG: Bulgaria (България)
 BH:       ar-BH: Bahrain (البحرين)
 BI:       en-BI: Burundi (Burundi)
 BI:       fr-BI: Burundi (Burundi)
 BI:       rn-BI: Burundi (Uburundi)
 BJ:       fr-BJ: Benin (Bénin)
 BJ:       yo-BJ: Benin (Orílɛ́ède Bɛ̀nɛ̀)
 BL:       fr-BL: Saint Barthélemy (Saint-Barthélemy)
 BM:       en-BM: Bermuda (Bermuda)
 BN:       ms-BN: Brunei (Brunei)
 BO:       es-BO: Bolivia (Bolivia)
 BO:      quz-BO: Bolivia (Bolivia)
 BQ:       nl-BQ: Bonaire, Sint Eustatius and Saba (Bonaire, Sint Eustatius en Saba)
 BR:       es-BR: Brazil (Brasil)
 BR:       pt-BR: Brazil (Brasil)
 BS:       en-BS: Bahamas (Bahamas)
 BT:       dz-BT: Bhutan (འབྲུག)
 BW:       en-BW: Botswana (Botswana)
 BW:       tn-BW: Botswana (Botswana)
 BY:       be-BY: Belarus (Беларусь)
 BY:       ru-BY: Belarus (Беларусь)
 BZ:       en-BZ: Belize (Belize)
 BZ:       es-BZ: Belize (Belice)
 CA:       en-CA: Canada (Canada)
 CA:       fr-CA: Canada (Canada)
 CA:  iu-Cans-CA: Canada (ᑲᓇᑕ)
 CA:  iu-Latn-CA: Canada (Kanata)
 CA:      moh-CA: Canada (Canada)
 CC:       en-CC: Cocos (Keeling) Islands (Cocos (Keeling) Islands)
 CD:       fr-CD: Congo (DRC) (Congo, République démocratique du)
 CD:       ln-CD: Congo (DRC) (Republíki ya Kongó Demokratíki)
 CD:       lu-CD: Congo (DRC) (Ditunga wa Kongu)
 CD:       sw-CD: Congo (DRC) (Jamhuri ya Kidemokrasia ya Kongo)
 CF:       fr-CF: Central African Republic (République centrafricaine)
 CF:       ln-CF: Central African Republic (Repibiki ya Afríka ya Káti)
 CF:       sg-CF: Central African Republic (Ködörösêse tî Bêafrîka)
 CG:       fr-CG: Congo (Congo)
 CG:       ln-CG: Congo (Kongo)
 CH:       de-CH: Switzerland (Schweiz)
 CH:       en-CH: Switzerland (Switzerland)
 CH:       fr-CH: Switzerland (Suisse)
 CH:      gsw-CH: Switzerland (Schwiiz)
 CH:       it-CH: Switzerland (Svizzera)
 CH:       pt-CH: Switzerland (Suíça)
 CH:       rm-CH: Switzerland (Svizra)
 CH:      wae-CH: Switzerland (Schwiz)
 CI:       fr-CI: Côte d’Ivoire (Côte d’Ivoire)
 CK:       en-CK: Cook Islands (Cook Islands)
 CL:      arn-CL: Chile (Chile)
 CL:       es-CL: Chile (Chile)
 CM:      agq-CM: Cameroon (Kàmàlûŋ)
 CM:      bas-CM: Cameroon (Kàmɛ̀rûn)
 CM:      dua-CM: Cameroon (Cameroun)
 CM:       en-CM: Cameroon (Cameroon)
 CM:      ewo-CM: Cameroon (Kamərún)
 CM:       ff-CM: Cameroon (Kameruun)
 CM:       fr-CM: Cameroon (Cameroun)
 CM:      jgo-CM: Cameroon (Kamɛlûn)
 CM:      kkj-CM: Cameroon (Kamɛrun)
 CM:      ksf-CM: Cameroon (kamɛrún)
 CM:      mgo-CM: Cameroon (Kamalun)
 CM:      mua-CM: Cameroon (kameruŋ)
 CM:      nmg-CM: Cameroon (Kamerun)
 CM:      nnh-CM: Cameroon (Kàmalûm)
 CM:      yav-CM: Cameroon (Kemelún)
 CN:       bo-CN: China (ཀྲུང་ཧྭ་མི་དམངས་སྤྱི་མཐུན་རྒྱལ་ཁབ།)
 CN:       ii-CN: China (ꍏꉸꏓꂱꇭꉼꇩ)
 CN:  mn-Mong-CN: China (ᠪᠦᠭᠦᠳᠡ ᠨᠠᠢᠷᠠᠮᠳᠠᠬᠤ ᠳᠤᠮᠳᠠᠳᠤ ᠠᠷᠠᠳ ᠣᠯᠣᠰ)
 CN:       ug-CN: China (جۇڭخۇا خەلق جۇمھۇرىيىتى)
 CN:       zh-CN: China (中国)
 CO:       es-CO: Colombia (Colombia)
 CR:       es-CR: Costa Rica (Costa Rica)
 CU:       es-CU: Cuba (Cuba)
 CV:      kea-CV: Cabo Verde (Kabu Verdi)
 CV:       pt-CV: Cabo Verde (Cabo Verde)
 CW:       nl-CW: Curaçao (Curaçao)
 CX:       en-CX: Christmas Island (Christmas Island)
 CY:       el-CY: Cyprus (Κύπρος)
 CY:       en-CY: Cyprus (Cyprus)
 CY:       tr-CY: Cyprus (Kıbrıs)
 CZ:       cs-CZ: Czechia (Česko)
 DE:       de-DE: Germany (Deutschland)
 DE:      dsb-DE: Germany (Nimska)
 DE:       en-DE: Germany (Germany)
 DE:      hsb-DE: Germany (Němska)
 DE:      ksh-DE: Germany (Doütschland)
 DE:      nds-DE: Germany (Düütschland)
 DJ:       aa-DJ: Djibouti (Yabuuti)
 DJ:       ar-DJ: Djibouti (جيبوتي)
 DJ:       fr-DJ: Djibouti (Djibouti)
 DJ:       so-DJ: Djibouti (Jabuuti)
 DK:       da-DK: Denmark (Danmark)
 DK:       en-DK: Denmark (Denmark)
 DK:       fo-DK: Denmark (Danmark)
 DM:       en-DM: Dominica (Dominica)
 DO:       es-DO: Dominican Republic (República Dominicana)
 DZ:       ar-DZ: Algeria (الجزائر)
 DZ:       fr-DZ: Algeria (Algérie)
 DZ:      kab-DZ: Algeria (Lezzayer)
 DZ: tzm-Latn-DZ: Algeria (Djazaïr)
 EC:       es-EC: Ecuador (Ecuador)
 EC:      quz-EC: Ecuador (Ecuador)
 EE:       et-EE: Estonia (Eesti)
 EG:       ar-EG: Egypt (مصر)
 ER:       aa-ER: Eritrea (Eretria)
 ER:       ar-ER: Eritrea (إريتريا)
 ER:      byn-ER: Eritrea (ኤርትራ)
 ER:       en-ER: Eritrea (Eritrea)
 ER:      ssy-ER: Eritrea (Eretria)
 ER:       ti-ER: Eritrea (ኤርትራ)
 ER:      tig-ER: Eritrea (ኤርትራ)
 ES:      ast-ES: Spain (España)
 ES:       ca-ES: Spain (Espanya)
 ES: ca-ES-valencia: Spain (Espanya)
 ES:       es-ES: Spain (España)
 ES:       eu-ES: Spain (Espainia)
 ES:       gl-ES: Spain (España)
 ET:       aa-ET: Ethiopia (Otobbia)
 ET:       am-ET: Ethiopia (ኢትዮጵያ)
 ET:       om-ET: Ethiopia (Itoophiyaa)
 ET:       so-ET: Ethiopia (Itoobiya)
 ET:       ti-ET: Ethiopia (ኢትዮጵያ)
 ET:      wal-ET: Ethiopia (ኢትዮጵያ)
 FI:       en-FI: Finland (Finland)
 FI:       fi-FI: Finland (Suomi)
 FI:       se-FI: Finland (Suopma)
 FI:      smn-FI: Finland (Suomâ)
 FI:      sms-FI: Finland (Lää´ddjânnam)
 FI:       sv-FI: Finland (Finland)
 FJ:       en-FJ: Fiji (Fiji)
 FK:       en-FK: Falkland Islands (Falkland Islands)
 FM:       en-FM: Micronesia (Micronesia)
 FO:       fo-FO: Faroe Islands (Føroyar)
 FR:       br-FR: France (Frañs)
 FR:       ca-FR: France (França)
 FR:       co-FR: France (Francia)
 FR:       fr-FR: France (France)
 FR:      gsw-FR: France (Frànkrisch)
 FR:       ia-FR: France (Francia)
 FR:       oc-FR: France (França)
 GA:       fr-GA: Gabon (Gabon)
 GB:       cy-GB: United Kingdom (Y Deyrnas Unedig)
 GB:       en-GB: United Kingdom (United Kingdom)
 GB:       gd-GB: United Kingdom (An Rìoghachd Aonaichte)
 GB:       kw-GB: United Kingdom (Rywvaneth Unys)
 GD:       en-GD: Grenada (Grenada)
 GE:       ka-GE: Georgia (საქართველო)
 GE:       os-GE: Georgia (Гуырдзыстон)
 GF:       fr-GF: French Guiana (Guyane française)
 GG:       en-GG: Guernsey (Guernsey)
 GH:       ak-GH: Ghana (Gaana)
 GH:       ee-GH: Ghana (Ghana nutome)
 GH:       en-GH: Ghana (Ghana)
 GH:  ha-Latn-GH: Ghana (Gana)
 GI:       en-GI: Gibraltar (Gibraltar)
 GL:       da-GL: Greenland (Grønland)
 GL:       kl-GL: Greenland (Kalaallit Nunaat)
 GM:       en-GM: Gambia (Gambia)
 GN:       ff-GN: Guinea (Gine)
 GN:       fr-GN: Guinea (Guinée)
 GN:      nqo-GN: Guinea (ߖߌ߬ߣߍ߬ ߞߊ߲ߓߍ߲)
 GP:       fr-GP: Guadeloupe (Guadeloupe)
 GQ:       es-GQ: Equatorial Guinea (Guinea Ecuatorial)
 GQ:       fr-GQ: Equatorial Guinea (Guinée équatoriale)
 GQ:       pt-GQ: Equatorial Guinea (Guiné Equatorial)
 GR:       el-GR: Greece (Ελλάδα)
 GT:       es-GT: Guatemala (Guatemala)
 GT: quc-Latn-GT: Guatemala (Guatemala)
 GU:       en-GU: Guam (Guam)
 GW:       pt-GW: Guinea-Bissau (Guiné-Bissau)
 GY:       en-GY: Guyana (Guyana)
 HK:       en-HK: Hong Kong SAR (Hong Kong SAR)
 HK:  zh-Hans-HK: Hong Kong SAR (香港特别行政区)
 HK:       zh-HK: Hong Kong SAR (香港特別行政區)
 HN:       es-HN: Honduras (Honduras)
 HR:       hr-HR: Croatia (Hrvatska)
 HT:       fr-HT: Haiti (Haïti)
 HU:       hu-HU: Hungary (Magyarország)
 ID:       en-ID: Indonesia (Indonesia)
 ID:       id-ID: Indonesia (Indonesia)
 ID:  jv-Java-ID: Indonesia (Indonesia)
 ID:  jv-Latn-ID: Indonesia (Indonesia)
 IE:       en-IE: Ireland (Ireland)
 IE:       ga-IE: Ireland (Éire)
 IL:       ar-IL: Israel (إسرائيل)
 IL:       en-IL: Israel (Israel)
 IL:       he-IL: Israel (ישראל)
 IM:       en-IM: Isle of Man (Isle of Man)
 IM:       gv-IM: Isle of Man (Ellan Vannin)
 IN:       as-IN: India (ভাৰত)
 IN:       bn-IN: India (ভারত)
 IN:       bo-IN: India (རྒྱ་གར་)
 IN:      brx-IN: India (भारत)
 IN:       en-IN: India (India)
 IN:       gu-IN: India (ભારત)
 IN:       hi-IN: India (भारत)
 IN:       kn-IN: India (ಭಾರತ)
 IN:      kok-IN: India (भारत)
 IN:  ks-Arab-IN: India (ہِنٛدوستان)
 IN:  ks-Deva-IN: India (India)
 IN:       ml-IN: India (ഇന്ത്യ)
 IN:      mni-IN: India (India)
 IN:       mr-IN: India (भारत)
 IN:       ne-IN: India (भारत)
 IN:       or-IN: India (ଭାରତ)
 IN:       pa-IN: India (ਭਾਰਤ)
 IN:       sa-IN: India (भारतम्)
 IN:  sd-Deva-IN: India (India)
 IN:       ta-IN: India (இந்தியா)
 IN:       te-IN: India (భారత దేశం)
 IN:       ur-IN: India (بھارت)
 IO:       en-IO: British Indian Ocean Territory (British Indian Ocean Territory)
 IQ:       ar-IQ: Iraq (العراق)
 IQ:  ku-Arab-IQ: Iraq (عێراق)
 IQ:      lrc-IQ: Iraq (Iraq)
 IR:       fa-IR: Iran (ایران)
 IR:  ku-Arab-IR: Iran (ئێران)
 IR:      lrc-IR: Iran (Iran)
 IR:      mzn-IR: Iran (ایران)
 IS:       is-IS: Iceland (Ísland)
 IT:       ca-IT: Italy (Itàlia)
 IT:       de-IT: Italy (Italien)
 IT:      fur-IT: Italy (Italie)
 IT:       it-IT: Italy (Italia)
 JE:       en-JE: Jersey (Jersey)
 JM:       en-JM: Jamaica (Jamaica)
 JO:       ar-JO: Jordan (الأردن)
 JP:       ja-JP: Japan (日本)
 KE:      dav-KE: Kenya (Kenya)
 KE:      ebu-KE: Kenya (Kenya)
 KE:       en-KE: Kenya (Kenya)
 KE:      guz-KE: Kenya (Kenya)
 KE:      kam-KE: Kenya (Kenya)
 KE:       ki-KE: Kenya (Kenya)
 KE:      kln-KE: Kenya (Emetab Kenya)
 KE:      luo-KE: Kenya (Kenya)
 KE:      luy-KE: Kenya (Kenya)
 KE:      mas-KE: Kenya (Kenya)
 KE:      mer-KE: Kenya (Kenya)
 KE:       om-KE: Kenya (Keeniyaa)
 KE:      saq-KE: Kenya (Kenya)
 KE:       so-KE: Kenya (Kiiniya)
 KE:       sw-KE: Kenya (Kenya)
 KE:      teo-KE: Kenya (Kenia)
 KG:       ky-KG: Kyrgyzstan (Кыргызстан)
 KG:       ru-KG: Kyrgyzstan (Киргизия)
 KH:       km-KH: Cambodia (កម្ពុជា)
 KI:       en-KI: Kiribati (Kiribati)
 KM:       ar-KM: Comoros (جزر القمر)
 KM:       fr-KM: Comoros (Comores)
 KN:       en-KN: Saint Kitts and Nevis (Saint Kitts and Nevis)
 KP:       ko-KP: North Korea (조선민주주의인민공화국)
 KR:       ko-KR: Korea (대한민국)
 KW:       ar-KW: Kuwait (الكويت)
 KY:       en-KY: Cayman Islands (Cayman Islands)
 KZ:       kk-KZ: Kazakhstan (Қазақстан)
 KZ:       ru-KZ: Kazakhstan (Казахстан)
 LA:       lo-LA: Laos (ລາວ)
 LB:       ar-LB: Lebanon (لبنان)
 LC:       en-LC: Saint Lucia (Saint Lucia)
 LI:       de-LI: Liechtenstein (Liechtenstein)
 LI:      gsw-LI: Liechtenstein (Liächteschtäi)
 LK:       si-LK: Sri Lanka (ශ්‍රී ලංකාව)
 LK:       ta-LK: Sri Lanka (இலங்கை)
 LR:       en-LR: Liberia (Liberia)
 LR: vai-Latn-LR: Liberia (Laibhiya)
 LR: vai-Vaii-LR: Liberia (ꕞꔤꔫꕩ)
 LS:       en-LS: Lesotho (Lesotho)
 LS:       st-LS: Lesotho (Lesotho)
 LT:       lt-LT: Lithuania (Lietuva)
 LU:       de-LU: Luxembourg (Luxemburg)
 LU:       fr-LU: Luxembourg (Luxembourg)
 LU:       lb-LU: Luxembourg (Lëtzebuerg)
 LU:       pt-LU: Luxembourg (Luxemburgo)
 LV:       lv-LV: Latvia (Latvija)
 LY:       ar-LY: Libya (ليبيا)
 MA:       ar-MA: Morocco (المملكة المغربية)
 MA:       fr-MA: Morocco (Maroc)
 MA: shi-Latn-MA: Morocco (lmɣrib)
 MA: shi-Tfng-MA: Morocco (ⵍⵎⵖⵔⵉⴱ)
 MA: tzm-Arab-MA: Morocco (Morocco)
 MA: tzm-Latn-MA: Morocco (Meṛṛuk)
 MA: tzm-Tfng-MA: Morocco (ⵍⵎⵖⵔⵉⴱ)
 MA: zgh-Tfng-MA: Morocco (ⵍⵎⵖⵔⵉⴱ)
 MC:       fr-MC: Monaco (Monaco)
 MD:       ro-MD: Moldova (Republica Moldova)
 MD:       ru-MD: Moldova (Молдова)
 ME:  sr-Cyrl-ME: Montenegro (Црна Гора)
 ME:  sr-Latn-ME: Montenegro (Crna Gora)
 MF:       fr-MF: Saint Martin (Saint-Martin)
 MG:       en-MG: Madagascar (Madagascar)
 MG:       fr-MG: Madagascar (Madagascar)
 MG:       mg-MG: Madagascar (Madagasikara)
 MH:       en-MH: Marshall Islands (Marshall Islands)
 MK:       mk-MK: Macedonia, FYRO (Република Македонија)
 MK:       sq-MK: Macedonia, FYRO (Republika e Maqedonisë)
 ML:  bm-Latn-ML: Mali (Mali)
 ML:       fr-ML: Mali (Mali)
 ML:      khq-ML: Mali (Maali)
 ML:      ses-ML: Mali (Maali)
 MM:       my-MM: Myanmar (မြန်မာ)
 MN:       mn-MN: Mongolia (Монгол)
 MN:  mn-Mong-MN: Mongolia (ᠮᠣᠩᠭᠣᠯ ᠣᠯᠣᠰ)
 MO:       en-MO: Macao SAR (Macao SAR)
 MO:       pt-MO: Macao SAR (RAE de Macau)
 MO:  zh-Hans-MO: Macao SAR (澳门特别行政区)
 MO:       zh-MO: Macao SAR (澳門特別行政區)
 MP:       en-MP: Northern Mariana Islands (Northern Mariana Islands)
 MQ:       fr-MQ: Martinique (Martinique)
 MR:       ar-MR: Mauritania (موريتانيا)
 MR:       ff-MR: Mauritania (Muritani)
 MR:       fr-MR: Mauritania (Mauritanie)
 MS:       en-MS: Montserrat (Montserrat)
 MT:       en-MT: Malta (Malta)
 MT:       mt-MT: Malta (Malta)
 MU:       en-MU: Mauritius (Mauritius)
 MU:       fr-MU: Mauritius (Maurice)
 MU:      mfe-MU: Mauritius (Moris)
 MV:       dv-MV: Maldives (ދިވެހި ރާއްޖެ)
 MW:       en-MW: Malawi (Malawi)
 MX:       es-MX: Mexico (México)
 MY:       en-MY: Malaysia (Malaysia)
 MY:       ms-MY: Malaysia (Malaysia)
 MY:       ta-MY: Malaysia (மலேசியா)
 MZ:      mgh-MZ: Mozambique (Umozambiki)
 MZ:       pt-MZ: Mozambique (Moçambique)
 MZ:      seh-MZ: Mozambique (Moçambique)
 NA:       af-NA: Namibia (Namibië)
 NA:       en-NA: Namibia (Namibia)
 NA:      naq-NA: Namibia (Namibiab)
 NC:       fr-NC: New Caledonia (Nouvelle-Calédonie)
 NE:      dje-NE: Niger (Nižer)
 NE:       fr-NE: Niger (Niger)
 NE:  ha-Latn-NE: Niger (Nijar)
 NE:      twq-NE: Niger (Nižer)
 NF:       en-NF: Norfolk Island (Norfolk Island)
 NG:      bin-NG: Nigeria (Nigeria)
 NG:       en-NG: Nigeria (Nigeria)
 NG:       ff-NG: Nigeria (Nigeria)
 NG:  ha-Latn-NG: Nigeria (Najeriya)
 NG:      ibb-NG: Nigeria (Nigeria)
 NG:       ig-NG: Nigeria (Naịjịrịa)
 NG:       kr-NG: Nigeria (Nigeria)
 NG:       yo-NG: Nigeria (Orílẹ́ède Nàìjíríà)
 NI:       es-NI: Nicaragua (Nicaragua)
 NL:       en-NL: Netherlands (Netherlands)
 NL:       fy-NL: Netherlands (Nederlân)
 NL:      nds-NL: Netherlands (Nedderlannen)
 NL:       nl-NL: Netherlands (Nederland)
 NO:       nb-NO: Norway (Norge)
 NO:       nn-NO: Norway (Noreg)
 NO:       se-NO: Norway (Norga)
 NO:      sma-NO: Norway (Nöörje)
 NO:      smj-NO: Norway (Vuodna)
 NP:       ne-NP: Nepal (नेपाल)
 NR:       en-NR: Nauru (Nauru)
 NU:       en-NU: Niue (Niue)
 NZ:       en-NZ: New Zealand (New Zealand)
 NZ:       mi-NZ: New Zealand (Aotearoa)
 OM:       ar-OM: Oman (عمان)
 PA:       es-PA: Panama (Panamá)
 PE:       es-PE: Peru (Perú)
 PE:      quz-PE: Peru (Perú)
 PF:       fr-PF: French Polynesia (Polynésie française)
 PG:       en-PG: Papua New Guinea (Papua New Guinea)
 PH:       en-PH: Philippines (Philippines)
 PH:       es-PH: Philippines (Filipinas)
 PH:      fil-PH: Philippines (Pilipinas)
 PK:       en-PK: Pakistan (Pakistan)
 PK:  pa-Arab-PK: Pakistan (پاکستان)
 PK:  sd-Arab-PK: Pakistan (پاکستان)
 PK:       ur-PK: Pakistan (پاکستان)
 PL:       pl-PL: Poland (Polska)
 PM:       fr-PM: Saint Pierre and Miquelon (Saint-Pierre-et-Miquelon)
 PN:       en-PN: Pitcairn Islands (Pitcairn Islands)
 PR:       en-PR: Puerto Rico (Puerto Rico)
 PR:       es-PR: Puerto Rico (Puerto Rico)
 PS:       ar-PS: Palestinian Authority (السلطة الفلسطينية)
 PT:       pt-PT: Portugal (Portugal)
 PW:       en-PW: Palau (Palau)
 PY:       es-PY: Paraguay (Paraguay)
 PY:       gn-PY: Paraguay (Paraguái)
 QA:       ar-QA: Qatar (قطر)
 RE:       fr-RE: Réunion (La Réunion)
 RO:       ro-RO: Romania (România)
 RS:  sr-Cyrl-RS: Serbia (Србија)
 RS:  sr-Latn-RS: Serbia (Srbija)
 RU:       ba-RU: Russia (Рәсәй)
 RU:       ce-RU: Russia (Росси)
 RU:       cu-RU: Russia (рѡссі́а)
 RU:       os-RU: Russia (Уӕрӕсе)
 RU:       ru-RU: Russia (Россия)
 RU:      sah-RU: Russia (Россия)
 RU:       tt-RU: Russia (Россия)
 RW:       en-RW: Rwanda (Rwanda)
 RW:       fr-RW: Rwanda (Rwanda)
 RW:       rw-RW: Rwanda (U Rwanda)
 SA:       ar-SA: Saudi Arabia (المملكة العربية السعودية)
 SB:       en-SB: Solomon Islands (Solomon Islands)
 SC:       en-SC: Seychelles (Seychelles)
 SC:       fr-SC: Seychelles (Seychelles)
 SD:       ar-SD: Sudan (السودان)
 SD:       en-SD: Sudan (Sudan)
 SE:       en-SE: Sweden (Sweden)
 SE:       se-SE: Sweden (Ruoŧŧa)
 SE:      sma-SE: Sweden (Sveerje)
 SE:      smj-SE: Sweden (Svierik)
 SE:       sv-SE: Sweden (Sverige)
 SG:       en-SG: Singapore (Singapore)
 SG:       ms-SG: Singapore (Singapura)
 SG:       ta-SG: Singapore (சிங்கப்பூர்)
 SG:       zh-SG: Singapore (新加坡)
 SH:       en-SH: St Helena, Ascension, Tristan da Cunha (St Helena, Ascension, Tristan da Cunha)
 SI:       en-SI: Slovenia (Slovenia)
 SI:       sl-SI: Slovenia (Slovenija)
 SJ:       nb-SJ: Svalbard and Jan Mayen (Svalbard og Jan Mayen)
 SK:       sk-SK: Slovakia (Slovensko)
 SL:       en-SL: Sierra Leone (Sierra Leone)
 SM:       it-SM: San Marino (San Marino)
 SN:      dyo-SN: Senegal (Senegal)
 SN:  ff-Latn-SN: Senegal (Senegaal)
 SN:       fr-SN: Senegal (Sénégal)
 SN:       wo-SN: Senegal (Senegaal)
 SO:       ar-SO: Somalia (الصومال)
 SO:       so-SO: Somalia (Soomaaliya)
 SR:       nl-SR: Suriname (Suriname)
 SS:       ar-SS: South Sudan (جنوب السودان)
 SS:       en-SS: South Sudan (South Sudan)
 SS:      nus-SS: South Sudan (South Sudan)
 ST:       pt-ST: São Tomé and Príncipe (São Tomé e Príncipe)
 SV:       es-SV: El Salvador (El Salvador)
 SX:       en-SX: Sint Maarten (Sint Maarten)
 SX:       nl-SX: Sint Maarten (Sint-Maarten)
 SY:       ar-SY: Syria (سوريا)
 SY:       fr-SY: Syria (Syrie)
 SY:      syr-SY: Syria (ܣܘܪܝܐ)
 SZ:       en-SZ: Swaziland (Swaziland)
 SZ:       ss-SZ: Swaziland (Swaziland)
 TC:       en-TC: Turks and Caicos Islands (Turks and Caicos Islands)
 TD:       ar-TD: Chad (تشاد)
 TD:       fr-TD: Chad (Tchad)
 TG:       ee-TG: Togo (Togo nutome)
 TG:       fr-TG: Togo (Togo)
 TH:       th-TH: Thailand (ไทย)
 TJ:  tg-Cyrl-TJ: Tajikistan (Тоҷикистон)
 TK:       en-TK: Tokelau (Tokelau)
 TL:       pt-TL: Timor-Leste (Timor-Leste)
 TM:       tk-TM: Turkmenistan (Türkmenistan)
 TN:       ar-TN: Tunisia (تونس)
 TN:       fr-TN: Tunisia (Tunisie)
 TO:       en-TO: Tonga (Tonga)
 TO:       to-TO: Tonga (Tonga)
 TR:       tr-TR: Turkey (Türkiye)
 TT:       en-TT: Trinidad and Tobago (Trinidad and Tobago)
 TV:       en-TV: Tuvalu (Tuvalu)
 TW:       zh-TW: Taiwan (台灣)
 TZ:      asa-TZ: Tanzania (Tadhania)
 TZ:      bez-TZ: Tanzania (Hutanzania)
 TZ:       en-TZ: Tanzania (Tanzania)
 TZ:      jmc-TZ: Tanzania (Tanzania)
 TZ:      kde-TZ: Tanzania (Tanzania)
 TZ:      ksb-TZ: Tanzania (Tanzania)
 TZ:      lag-TZ: Tanzania (Taansanía)
 TZ:      mas-TZ: Tanzania (Tansania)
 TZ:      rof-TZ: Tanzania (Tanzania)
 TZ:      rwk-TZ: Tanzania (Tanzania)
 TZ:      sbp-TZ: Tanzania (Tansaniya)
 TZ:       sw-TZ: Tanzania (Tanzania)
 TZ:      vun-TZ: Tanzania (Tanzania)
 UA:       ru-UA: Ukraine (Украина)
 UA:       uk-UA: Ukraine (Україна)
 UG:      cgg-UG: Uganda (Uganda)
 UG:       en-UG: Uganda (Uganda)
 UG:       lg-UG: Uganda (Yuganda)
 UG:      nyn-UG: Uganda (Uganda)
 UG:       sw-UG: Uganda (Uganda)
 UG:      teo-UG: Uganda (Uganda)
 UG:      xog-UG: Uganda (Yuganda)
 UM:       en-UM: U.S. Outlying Islands (U.S. Outlying Islands)
 US: chr-Cher-US: United States (ᏌᏊ ᎢᏳᎾᎵᏍᏔᏅ ᏍᎦᏚᎩ)
 US:       en-US: United States (United States)
 US:       es-US: United States (Estados Unidos)
 US:      haw-US: United States (ʻAmelika Hui Pū ʻIa)
 US:      lkt-US: United States (Mílahaŋska Tȟamákȟočhe)
 UY:       es-UY: Uruguay (Uruguay)
 UZ:  uz-Cyrl-UZ: Uzbekistan (Ўзбекистон)
 UZ:  uz-Latn-UZ: Uzbekistan (Oʻzbekiston)
 VA:       it-VA: Vatican City (Città del Vaticano)
 VC:       en-VC: Saint Vincent and the Grenadines (Saint Vincent and the Grenadines)
 VE:       es-VE: Venezuela (Venezuela)
 VG:       en-VG: British Virgin Islands (British Virgin Islands)
 VI:       en-VI: U.S. Virgin Islands (U.S. Virgin Islands)
 VN:       vi-VN: Vietnam (Việt Nam)
 VU:       en-VU: Vanuatu (Vanuatu)
 VU:       fr-VU: Vanuatu (Vanuatu)
 WF:       fr-WF: Wallis and Futuna (Wallis-et-Futuna)
 WS:       en-WS: Samoa (Samoa)
 XK:       sq-XK: Kosovo (Kosovë)
 XK:  sr-Cyrl-XK: Kosovo (Косово)
 XK:  sr-Latn-XK: Kosovo (Kosovo)
 YE:       ar-YE: Yemen (اليمن)
 YT:       fr-YT: Mayotte (Mayotte)
 ZA:       af-ZA: South Africa (Suid-Afrika)
 ZA:       en-ZA: South Africa (South Africa)
 ZA:       nr-ZA: South Africa (South Africa)
 ZA:      nso-ZA: South Africa (Afrika Borwa)
 ZA:       ss-ZA: South Africa (South Africa)
 ZA:       st-ZA: South Africa (South Africa)
 ZA:       tn-ZA: South Africa (Aforika Borwa)
 ZA:       ts-ZA: South Africa (South Africa)
 ZA:       ve-ZA: South Africa (South Africa)
 ZA:       xh-ZA: South Africa (eMzantsi Afrika)
 ZA:       zu-ZA: South Africa (iNingizimu Afrika)
 ZM:      bem-ZM: Zambia (Zambia)
 ZM:       en-ZM: Zambia (Zambia)
 ZW:       en-ZW: Zimbabwe (Zimbabwe)
 ZW:       nd-ZW: Zimbabwe (Zimbabwe)
 ZW:  sn-Latn-ZW: Zimbabwe (Zimbabwe)
```

**Edit:** Updated to what is seen om my Windows 10 (version 1803 "April 2018 Update") machine, .NET Framework 4.7.2.