# Textbox currency several countries

Tags: vb.net, textbox, currency, countries

I found out that from these lines of code we could get the currency of **Canadian**.

```
 Dim value As Decimal = ourTextbox.text 
    Dim positiveValue As Decimal = ourTextbox.text 
    Dim customCurrencyInfo As CultureInfo = CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture("fr-CA")

    customCurrencyInfo.NumberFormat.CurrencyNegativePattern = 8

    Dim formatString As String = value.ToString("C", customCurrencyInfo)
    Dim formatStringPositive As String = positiveValue.ToString("C", customCurrencyInfo)

    myTextbox.text = formatString
    myTextbox2.text = formatStringPositive
```

The output would be;

> -123,45 $ 123,45 $

But what about these countries:

**-Malaysia

-Indonesia

-Somalia / Africa

-Arabia**

How to get their currency shown on the formatting textbox?

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Comment: You can find culture info here... http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/goglobal/bb896001.aspx

Comment: info on defining / extending culture info: http://stackoverflow.com/a/223661/1070452

Comment: alright.... i will remember it once i post some questions in the future.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pass different culture name as parameter of `CreateSpecificCulture()` method, for example :

```
'Malaysia'
Dim customCurrencyInfo As CultureInfo = CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture("my-MY")
'Indonesia'
Dim customCurrencyInfo As CultureInfo = CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture("id-ID")
'Afrikaans'
Dim customCurrencyInfo As CultureInfo = CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture("af")
'Arabic'
Dim customCurrencyInfo As CultureInfo = CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture("ar")
```

You can find culture name list in MSDN : [CultureInfo Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.cultureinfo%28vs.71%29.aspx)

Note: changing culture info not only change currency symbol but may also change decimal and thousand separator. If you want to avoid that, you can copy current culture

```
info and simply change it's currency symbol from other culture :
Dim customCurrencyInfo = (CultureInfo)CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.Clone();
Dim culture As CultureInfo = CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture("id-ID")
customCurrencyInfo.NumberFormat.CurrencySymbol = culture.NumberFormat.CurrencySymbol
```